# Application crashes when installed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have created setup files for a Visual Studio project. These are created by adding the project output to a setup project. Thereby all DLL files and the project itself is included.

When the application is installed on the machine which has been used for developing it, it works fine. However, when it is installed on another computer with a fresh Windows install (.NET Framework 4.0 is installed on it) the application crashes at startup - it don't even startup.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: usually because you have not included all dll. Does the pplication report any error?

Comment: Could be many things. Database connections, invalid configuration files, an assembly missing. A look in the event viewer could answer many questions. Also [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) could be of great help here.

Comment: Can you tell us what kind of application it is - WPF, WinForms, Console application, web site etc? Depending on what type of app, there should be some mechanism to catch or at least identify what exception is causing the application to crash.

Comment: Check the event log.  Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs.  Check the Application log.

Comment: The event viewer shows two errors for the program. A `XamlParseException' and thereafter an error with close to no details. "The process was terminated due to an uhandled exception. Exception info: System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException." Does anyone know what would cause this in an application which works fine on the machine used for development?

Comment: It could be a missing dependancy, folder, or even an icon. Check that any referenced DLL's aren't 32-bit and the code is 64-bit only or vice versa. Try Cleaning and Rebuilding the project too. Also, see the code below - sometimes the InnerException that's (hopefully!) caught will tell you what's missing. Hope one of those works! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a clue of what is crashing, you can catch unhandled exceptions from within Program.cs(or where Main() is) with the following:

```
        static void Application_ThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "Unhandled Thread Exception");
            // here you can log the exception ...
        }

        static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show((e.ExceptionObject as Exception).Message +
                "\r\n\r\nStack Trace:" +
                (e.ExceptionObject as Exception).InnerException.StackTrace, "Unhandled UI Exception");
            // here you can log the exception ...
        }
```

The messages will give you some clue. You should also check the event log, you may find some useful information there.

Answer (score 0):

First place I'd look is the Windows Event Log. It's highly likely the cause of your crash will be written to the Application Event log.

You could try catching all unhandled exceptions with [DispatcherUnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx) :

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        // Process unhandled exception

        // Prevent default unhandled exception processing
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

With that, you could add a small bit of code to write the Exception to a log file, or a MessageBox.